# What does [::-1] actually do in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Say I have something like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])

# this will get the indices of elements in reverse sorted order
a.argsort()[::-1]
```

I can imagine that `-1` specifies the direction, but what does the `::` operator do?
Is this a numpy thing or a python thing in general?

Comment: Frameworks can't add syntax to Python, so this is just a "Python thing". It's just the syntax for slices https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings

Comment: It's `from:to:stride`. The `stride` includes direction.

Comment: It is a python thing, I recommend to take a look at slicing https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1437986

Comment: This is python thing, see slices: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: It is standard Python indexing syntax.  As for what `numpy` actually does: it changes the `strides` to negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reverses the array:

```
In [149]: a = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60])
In [150]: b = a[::-1]
In [151]: b
Out[151]: array([60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10])
```

In detail the interpreter translates that indexing expression to:

```
In [152]: a.__getitem__(slice(None,None,-1))
Out[152]: array([60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10])
```

Under the covers `numpy` just returns a `view` with an change in `strides`:

```
In [153]: a.strides
Out[153]: (8,)
In [154]: b.strides
Out[154]: (-8,)
```

That -1 slice step can be used elsewhere

To reverse strings and lists:

```
In [155]: 'astring'[::-1]
Out[155]: 'gnirtsa'
In [156]: [1,2,3,4][::-1]
Out[156]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

and to generate numbers in 'reverse' order:

```
In [157]: np.arange(0,10,1)
Out[157]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [158]: np.arange(9,-1,-1)
Out[158]: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
In [160]: np.arange(9,-1,-3)
Out[160]: array([9, 6, 3, 0])
```

Here we have to specify the end points, while in slicing those can be `None`, and taken from the object's shape.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for the explanation, I've actually learned more from it than I was hoping to, so a big thanks!